# Eigenvectors of self-adjoint operators as Hilbert space basis

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics

My question is strongly related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074918/why-does-the-set-of-an-hermitian-operators-eigenfunctions-spans-the-functions-s), but I'd like to have a few more details about the topic.

**Question 1:** If $\mathscr{H}$ is a Hilbert space and $T$ is a self-adjoint operator on $\mathscr{H}$ with a countable set of eigenvectors $\{\psi_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, does it follow that $\{\psi_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ form a complete orthonormal set (i.e. a Hilbert basis) for $\mathscr{H}$? If so, can someone please explain *how* does it follow from the spectral theorem?

**Question 2:** In the linked question, a special attention was given to operators with continuous spectrum. In this case, it seems not to be possible to form a basis for $\mathscr{H}$ composed by eigenvectors of a self-adjoint operator $T$. But one of the answers speak of a "generalized eigenfunction", which is not properly an element of a Hilbert space. How does it work? Could someone please at least sketch the ideas?

Comment: #2 Do you want a hand-waving physics description? https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=generalized+eigenfunction

Comment: #1 Can you link to a statement of the [version of spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#General_self-adjoint_operators) you are using?

Comment: Q1: If $H$ is not separable then the eigenvectors cannot be  a complete orthonormal set. The closure of the span of the eigenvectors is equal to the orthogonal complement of the null-space of the operator.

Answer (score 3):

Let $H=L^2_{\mu}((-1,1)\cup\{1,1/2,1/3,\cdots\})$ where $\mu$ is ordinary Lebesgue measure on $(-1,0)$ and where $\mu$ has discrete atoms of unit mass on $\{ 1,1/2,1/3,1/4,\cdots \}$. The operator $A : H\rightarrow H$ defined as $(Af)(\lambda)=\lambda f(\lambda)$ is self adjoint with continuous spectrum on $(-1,0)$ and has discrete spectrum $\{1,1/2,1/3,\cdots\}$. The eigenvectors are $e_n=\chi_{{1/n}}$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$, but these do not form a complete basis of $H$. This type of operator comes up when studying the basic Hydrogen isotope in Physics, but the continuous spectrum is in $(0,\infty)$ instead. You have approximate eigenvectors with approximate eigenvalues $\lambda\in(-1,1)$, but no actual eigenvalues in that range.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Very nice. But if I assume $\mathscr{H}$ is separable, do these eigenvectors form a basis? Maybe I had to harden some hypothesis?

Comment: @MathMath : This Hilbert space is separable.